# Python findpeaks implementation difference with Matlab's

Tags: python, matlab, scipy

I'm interested in finding positive and negative peaks in a data sample with Python.

To give you a better idea, I'm considering Matlab's findpeaks function (https://it.mathworks.com/help/signal/ref/findpeaks.html).

For example, when in Matlab I do

```matlab
[a1,peak_loc1] = findpeaks(data,"DoubleSided",'MinPeakHeight',peak_height)
```

I get the peaks and the indices at which the peaks occur.

Now, I found a good candidate in the scipy signal find_peaks function (https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.signal.find_peaks.html).

This seems very similar. But as is, it does not provide the results I want. In fact it returns the peaks and a dictionary containing properties of the returned peaks.

So to return the a1 and peak_loc1 values I did a little extra operation:

```py
import numpy as np
from scipy.signal import find_peaks

def findpeaks(arr, h, w=1, d=1):
    pos = find_peaks(arr, height=h, width=w, distance=d)
    pos_list = dict(zip(pos[0], pos[1]['peak_heights']))

    neg = find_peaks(arr * -1, height=h, width=w, distance=d)
    neg_list = dict(zip(neg[0], neg[1]['peak_heights'] * -1))

    full_list = {**pos_list, **neg_list}
    full_list = dict(sorted(full_list.items()))

    heights = list(full_list.values())
    indexes = list(full_list.keys())

    return heights, indexes
```

However the results I get do not match 1:1 the results in Matlab.

To make the difference easier to see please take a look at this screenshot where I put the values side by side. On the left you have matlab's values and on the right Python's values.

[values comparison](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xNsuv.png)

Values in white are identical. However at some point there is wierdness going on where Matlab's corresponding value are shifted one position later. I highlighted the matching values with colors. And then there is two values (in red) which do not have any correspondence in the ones calculated by Python.

This is my Python code:

Please note data is a simple np.array but it has around 12K values in it, so you can look at it here: https://pastebin.pl/view/d3d5dba4

```py
data = *
peak_height = 0.4455
a1, peak_loc1 = findpeaks(data, peak_height)
```

What can be the reason? The only thing that came to my mind is that there is some parameter missing... i.e. what would correspond to "DoubleSided"? Given 'MinPeakHeight' should be the peak_height parameter I'm already passing to Python.

Comment: if it can be helpful, I can add a1 and peak_loc1 values Matlab is returning. Each one is made of 43 values as you can see in the screenshot.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the used parameter `DoubleSided` and your screenshot I'm assuming that you are actually using [Octave's `findpeaks`](https://octave.sourceforge.io/signal/function/findpeaks.html) rather than Matlab's! If you read that parameters description:

> **"DoubleSided"** - Tells the function that data takes positive and negative values. The base-line for the peaks is taken as the mean value of the function. This is equivalent as passing the absolute value of the data after removing the mean.

So using `DoubleSided` will actually manipulate absolute values in `data` before checking for `MinPeakHeight` and will therefore change which peaks fall below or above the height 0.4455. We can imitate this in Python (I took the liberty to simplify/speed up your function):

```py
def findpeaks(arr, h, w=1, d=1):
    # Adjust baseline to emulate 'DoubleSided'
    adjusted = arr - arr.mean()
    # Only consider absolute value to find local maxima AND minima
    adjusted = abs(adjusted)

    indexes, _ = find_peaks(adjusted, height=h)
    # Retrieve extrema heights from original signal rather
    # than from the properties dict with adjusted heights
    heights = arr[indexes]

    return heights, indexes

a1, peak_loc1 = findpeaks(data, h=0.4455)

for h, i in zip(a1, peak_loc1):
    # For display purpose, adjust index by +1
    # to match Octave/Matlab's indexing
    print(f"{h:>9.5f} | {i + 1:>5}")
```

Running this with your `data` will print values that look identical to Octave's output (at least I didn't find a difference).